# Do Taiwanese-Americans and Filipino-Americans have higher median incomes than White Americans?

Tags: united-states

According to Fox News anchor [Tucker Carlson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5UX4Trwqbc):

> if you look at household median income, the top three slots are not white man. They are all people of color that the number one is Indians and number two is Taiwanese and the third is I think the Filipino. So, white men are not making the most money in this country.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Household_income_in_the_United_States) has data for 2014's US household income excluding information regarding Filipino and Taiwanese Americans. Is his claim true that Taiwanese-Americans and Filipino-Americans have higher median incomes than White Americans?

Comment: Wikipedia gives comprehensive sources for it's figures. 2014 is very recent, in economic terms, and it is extremely unlikely that the figures have changed significantly in 2015 (2016 is almost certainly not available as I write). Are you questioning the figures in general, or looking for more recent exact figures?

Comment: The raw figures from which the Wikipedia article is taken include the figures for 2015: https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?src=bkmk

Comment: Seems entirely reasonable, when you look at the number of Indian & Chinese immigrants who come to this country to work in tech.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin Not as I write this. Having economic figures out two months after the end of the year would be unheard of. You can look at the site too.

Comment: You have rather recent data. There is no reason to believe it has changed. You don't seem to be actually doubting the claim. What are you hoping to get as an answer here?

Comment: @Oddthinking Question updated.

Comment: Given that you have well-sourced data supporting the statement, why are you skeptical about the statement? Any answer is probably going to cite as definitive exactly the data you have already linked to.

Comment: @DJClayworth I can't access the data. I don't know what is blocking it but it says "Please try your request again, starting from the American FactFinder Main Page.
If you continue to experience a problem, we suggest closing then restarting your browser."

Comment: You can search census data that shows asian-Americans have a higher median income then the general population and white Americans who are second.  Its also quite a bit higher,  over 20%.  Hispanics have a higher median income than Blacks who have the lowest.  This is a trend that has been pretty consistent for many years now.